# How to add patches for multiple kernel versions in buildroot?

Tags: linux, kernel, patch, buildroot

I have the following patch structure, I want to provide a set of patches for all 5.4 and above kernels and a separate set of patches for all 6.0 and above (6.1,6.2 and 6.3) versions.  Is there a way to do this within the buildroot (version 2023.02.3) structure?

This is my current buildroot external directory structure:

```
BR2_EXTERNAL/
    /packages
    /patches
        /linux
            /<version>
```